# how to make a timer that constantly gets faster

Tags: swift, timer

I am currently making a game for my class, and I need help with making a timer. My game is an arcade/endless game, where there are several tiles that need to be tapped, with a timer that slowly becomes shorter and shorter.

I was thinking maybe a `UIProgressView`that starts at ~1900 milliseconds or so and each time a tile is tapped it decreases by 5 milliseconds or so (not very noticeable at first, but it adds up) down to a minimum of like, ~200 or so milliseconds which is about a fifth of a second with this code

```swift
var timerTime :Int = 1900

func timerDecrement() {

    if (timerTime => 200) {

        timerTime = (timerTime - 5)

//OR
        timerTime--
        timerTime--
        timerTime--
        timerTime--
        timerTime--

    }

}
```

k, so using that code or something similar, i need to make an animated timer-thing (for example, a UIProgressView) because i've never used a timer, and my experimentations have been fruitless, so far.

Edit:
I can't add code until Monday because that's just how my school works .-.
I tried to make my UIPROGRESSVIEW count down but I just don't understand how it works to be honest.

Comment: Is your question how to create an algorithm, or how to use a timer in iOS? What are your fruitless experiments?

Comment: I agree with @Gruntcakes - please show your attempts so far, even if they're failing

Comment: What is ***SWIFT***?!

Answer (score 0):

I quickly created such a Timer (description in `interval` property documentation)
Init it with an interval and a callback, when the interval needs to change just change the interval property of this timer by doing something like `timer.interval -= 5`. Also you need to keep a reference of this timer somewhere, otherwise it's not going to work

```
//
//  VarTimer.swift
//  VarTimer
//
//  Created by Kametrixom on 29.05.15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Kametrixom Tikara. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

class Timer: NSObject {
    private var timer : NSTimer?
    private var lastTime : UInt64 = 0

    var handler : () -> ()

    var running : Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if running != oldValue {
                if running {
                    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                    lastTime = mach_absolute_time()
                } else {
                    timer?.invalidate()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// The time interval for this timer. If this value is changed, 
    /// the percentage that has been completed of the old interval
    /// is scaled to the new one.
    ///
    /// E.g.: Timer with 4 second interval is started, one second
    /// later (after a fourth or the time has passed) the interval
    /// is changed to 2 seconds, therefore the new timer will fire
    /// in 1.5 seconds (because a fourth has already been done with
    /// the old interval)
    var interval : NSTimeInterval {
        didSet {
            if interval != oldValue && running {
                timer?.invalidate()

                let nsec = UInt64(oldValue * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
                let percentDone = Double(mach_absolute_time() - lastTime) / Double(nsec)
                let fireDateShift = (1 - percentDone) * interval
                let fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(fireDateShift)

                timer = NSTimer(fireDate: fireDate, interval: interval, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer!, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
                lastTime = mach_absolute_time()
            }
        }
    }

    convenience init(interval: NSTimeInterval) {
        self.init(interval: interval, handler: {})
    }

    init(interval: NSTimeInterval, handler: () -> ()) {
        self.interval = interval
        self.handler = handler
        super.init()
    }

    func start() {
        running = true
    }

    func stop() {
        running = false
    }

    func update() {
        lastTime = mach_absolute_time()
        handler()
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try to dissect this and learn from it :) I've also got another question - Can I directly add this to an element of my ViewController such as a label or a UIProgressView?

Comment: @Hytoyotwo What do you mean by 'add'? Your view controller typically manages all the stuff, so it should be in there.